# How to delete specific items written on a textfile using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Given a user has to enter a full name, e-mail address,and phone number , which is then saved to a text file, now I want the user to be able to delete each record it wants. I used the code below:

Save Button

```
    deleteFile = "file path is copied here"

    Dim writer As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(deleteFile)
    user_text = TextBox1.Text
    e_mail = TextBox3.Text
    num = TextBox4.Text

    writer.WriteLine(user_text)
    writer.WriteLine(e_mail)
    writer.WriteLine(num)
    writer.WriteLine("*************")
    writer.Close()

    Dim rez As DialogResult
    rez = MessageBox.Show("Saved", " ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    If rez = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK = True Then
        TextBox1.Text = String.Empty

    End If

End Sub
```

Read Button

Dim reader1 As StreamReader = New StreamReader(deleteFile)

```
    Dim output As String
    While reader1.Peek <> -1
        output = reader1.ReadLine()
        ListBox1.Items.Add(output)
```

Delete Button

Me.sub1()

Sub sub1()

```
    Try
        Dim lines As New List(Of String)(IO.File.ReadAllLines("file path is copied here"))
    'remove the line to delete , 
        lines.RemoveAt(1)
        lines.RemoveAt(2)
        lines.RemoveAt(3)
        IO.File.WriteAllLines("file path is copied here", lines.ToArray())
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

When I press the Delete button I get the following exception message:
The process cannot access the file '(file path is shown here)' because it is being used by another process.

Thanks for taking your time to read the question.

Comment: Are you closing/disposing the StreamReader?

Comment: I don't get your question clearly, The read button displays data written on a text file to the listbox

Comment: Are you calling `reader1.Close()` when you're done reading from the file? Also, temporarily remove the try-catch block so that you know exactly on which line the exception occurs.